# F# mutable list is null

Tags: f#, specflow

**When I try to run the code below, properties is null. Why is that?** I assign an empty list to properties, but the first time through the loop, it is null.

This causes it to drop the first value that I append to it. I do not understand this either. It seems that a value concatenated with a null should be list of the value.

```
[<TechTalk.SpecFlow.Binding>]
module FSharpLeftistHeapStepDefinition

open TechTalk.SpecFlow

let mutable properties = [0]
let [<Given>] ``I have a list with the following numbers``(values:Table) = 
    let rec insertItems i =
        if i < 0 then ()
        else 
            let value = int ((values.Rows.Item i).Item 0)            
            properties <- value::properties
            insertItems (i-1)

    insertItems (values.RowCount - 1)
```

This is very strange.

[Edit]
The solution based on Tarmil's answer

```
 [<Binding>]
 type Example ()= 
     let mutable properties = []
     let [<Given>] ``I have a list with the following numbers``(values:Table) = 
         let rec insertItems i =
             if i < 0 then ()
             else 
                 let value = int ((values.Rows.Item i).Item 0)            
                 properties <- value::properties
                 insertItems (i-1)

         insertItems (values.RowCount - 1)
```

Comment: any particular reason to avoid TickSpec?

Comment: @RubenBartelink is TickSpec dead? no updates in 2 years.

Comment: @maslow I have a version in https://github.com/bartelink/tickspec where I show using it with xunit 2 (I wanted to run stuff in parallel) - I've never found a bug in TickSpec and it's 1000 lines ish of simple code. SpecFlow OTOH gives no benefits that I want and does not integrate as seamlessly with F# as TickSpec does so for me it's a no-brainer to pick it over SpecFlow (though raw xUnit in F# can come very close in terms of expressiveness, which is what we actually ended up using in the end). I believe Phil is open to rehoming it - e.g. under fssf control but also anyone who is actively using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this `[<Given>]` attribute comes from a testing framework, which makes me suspect that the assembly is loaded in a non-conventional way by it. The initial value `[0]` is set by the module's static constructor, so if this constructor is not run by the testing framework, then that would explain why it stays equal to `null`.