# Generating specflow stepdefinitions skeleton in f# instead of c#

Tags: f#, specflow

I have been trying to generate f# step definition skeleton file using context menu "Generate Step Definitions" in specflow. But it generates only c#. Is there a way that we tell user preferred language for step definitions. We have most of our acceptance tests written in F# already. Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using TickSpec?

Comment: The documentation wasn't clear on how to create the fixture. See my question if you get stuck where I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514966/f-mutable-list-is-null

Answer (score 1):

Specflow [has some support](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/FSharp-Support/) for F# and it seems that you have a template for generating the definitions when you don't copy them to the clipboard (see `Generate step definition skeletons from feature files (with custom templates)` on [this page](http://www.specflow.org/whatsnew-19/)).

It also seems that F# stepdefinitions are supported according to [this page](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Step-Definition-Styles/) and [this page on github](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Runtime/BindingSkeletons/DefaultSkeletonTemplates.sftemplate) shows that F# is included in the default templates.

Hopefully some of those links will guide you towards how you get specflow to use F# for the steps

Having thought about this a little more I would have thought you could hack this by editing the DefaultSkeletonTemplates.sftemplate file and replacing the c# template with the f# one to generate the f# templates.  This is almost certainly a Bad Idea - don't do it. But it might work