# How to replace the c# template with the f# one to generate the f# templates in BDD Specflow

Tags: f#, bdd, specflow

can you please let me know how to replace the c# template with the f# one to generate the f# templates..i have copied DefaultSkeletonTemplates.sftemplate file in C:\Users\AppData\Local\SpecFlow

i am referencing this thread
[Generating specflow stepdefinitions skeleton in f# instead of c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673044/generating-specflow-stepdefinitions-skeleton-in-f-instead-of-c-sharp)

Trying to generate F# template as per below write up

Customizing Step Definition Skeleton Templates
If you want to include a custom using statement or a base class declaration to the generated step definition skeletons, you can also customize the templates. Just place a text file called SkeletonTemplates.sftemplate into the SpecFlow folder inside your local app data (e.g. C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\SpecFlow\SkeletonTemplates.sftemplate) to override the necessary templates.

The template file contains sections, one for each template. In the custom template file you can override one or more sections. For all other sections, the default template will be used. The sections are separated with the >>> line prefix followed by the identifier of the section. The templates can refer to different parameters with the {param} syntax.

The following example overrides the class generation skeleton for C# and specifies a custom comment in the file header:

Source:-https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Step-Definition-Styles